# Programmatically logging in a user?

Tags: python, session, authentication, language-agnostic, proxy

Is it possible to sign into a website (and allow that website to be visited with any browser without the user having to sign in) via a background process without user interaction and allow the user to browse the site without logging in from any browser?

I'd guess that I would need to register the created session with each web browser on the user's system, but is there any other (possibly simpler) way of doing this?

Think of it like automatically signing into Gmail in the background and being able to browse it without ever seeing a login page.

Comment: You could, nominally, make a curl request to the website with an appropriate POST and then store the session ID in some cookie or another that you then pass through to each browser you use.  I wouldn't be surprised if different browsers had different formatting constraints, so that might be problematic.

Comment: @agam360: I'm doing this from within the user's computer, so I don't have access to the server. I'm looking for a way to automatically log in the user into a set of predefined websites (like Facebook, Gmail, Twitter, etc.) from within their own computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes is possible.I suggest two ways to solve your problem. Both of them uses HTTP requests. You should check more info about HTTP request.

1) the easiest way and recommended one for only login [Requests: HTTP for Humans](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html)

2) python scrapy, but scrapy is for crawling or screen scraping.
check this example:

Login spider example

```
class LoginSpider(BaseSpider):
name = 'example.com'
start_urls = ['http://www.example.com/users/login.php']

def parse(self, response):
    return [FormRequest.from_response(response,
                formdata={'username': 'john', 'password': 'secret'},
                callback=self.after_login)]

def after_login(self, response):
    # check login succeed before going on
    if "authentication failed" in response.body:
        self.log("Login failed", level=log.ERROR)
        return

    # continue scraping with authenticated session...
```

[more info here](http://readthedocs.org/docs/scrapy/en/latest/topics/request-response.html?highlight=scrapy%20login)

Comment: Would this register with the user's webbrowsers? I'm not really looking to scrape, but instead to login the user in the background so that they do not need to login when loading the page on their webbrowser.

Answer (score 0):

There is a library in python called urllib2 which will let you do what you need.  Look in the python docs or here:

http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/urllib2.shtml#openers-and-handlers

or this:

http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/urllib2/

Comment: I know how to authenticate via Python, but is there any way to authenticate the user's *browsers* with a Python script? I'm trying to login into certain sites without user interaction, so when the user visits the site, they are automatically logged in.